# How to identify type of client machine with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cross-platform, platform

```
Import platform
platform.machine()
```

that code can be used to identify type of machine we used. But how to identify type client machine who are connected to my network with python?

Comment: How are they connected?

Comment: with some wifi router device

Comment: You’re looking for system fingerprinting à la `nmap`.  Not much to do with Python.